# Sails js: select records from mysql?

Tags: mysql, typescript, sails.js

I am trying to select all records from table called fairCustomer where business_type_id equal array of value.
I am using sailsjs for server and mysql for DB, in frontend I am using nativescript with typescript.

and this is my code:

```js
 filterShopType(){
      this.service.serviceName = 'fairCustomers';
        this.service.Get({ populate:'country_id,business_type_id',where:{ business_type_id:{ in:this.business_ids_filter } }, limit:20 }).then((data: any) => {
            this.fairCustomers.splice(0, this.fairCustomers.length);
            this.fairCustomers.push(data);
            this.Refresh('fairCustomers');
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('failed get fairCustomers from server ', err);
        });
    }
```

**service** refer to http.request(), where i am using it in another place in my code.
**business_ids_filter** is an array of ids.
When I run this code the I am getting this error:

"**message**": "Could not parse the provided `where` clause.  Refer to the Sails documentation for up-to-date info on supported query language syntax:\n(http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language)\nDetails: Unrecognized sub-attribute modifier (`in`) for `business_type_id`.  Make sure to use a recognized sub-attribute modifier such as `startsWith`, `<=`, `!`, etc. )",

and if I removed **where** I got an error result.

***please anyone have any idea or solution?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working with me by using [or] instead of [in], this is the code

```js
    filterShopType(){
        if(this.business_ids_filter){
            this.service.serviceName = 'fairCustomers';
            var arr = [];
            this.business_ids_filter.forEach( (id) => {
                arr.push({ business_type_id: id })
            });
            let where = {};
            if(arr.length > 0){
                where = {or: arr};
            }
            this.service.Get({ populate: 'country_id,business_type_id',where:where , limit:20 }).then((data: any) => {
                this.filterItems.splice(0, this.filterItems.length);
                this.filterItems.push(data);
                this.Refresh('filterItems');
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('failed get fair Customers from server ', err);
            });
        }else{
            this.set('isFilter', false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try with a native query as described here, https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/send-native-query

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you could simply provide an array of items. Matches against ANY of the items in the array means that the record should be returned as part of the result. Not sure if it works in a `where`-clause though.

**Docs:**[Query Language](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language) (scroll to: In Modifier)

---

I do share your confusion as to why the given query does not work though, as the docs state that `in` should be valid, but perhaps it's not valid inside `where:{...}`? And I am assuming you are using `.find()` inside `.Get(...)`? Simply proxying the query unchanged through to `.find()`?

```js
 filterShopType(){
      this.service.serviceName = 'fairCustomers';
        this.service.Get({ 
            populate:'country_id, business_type_id',
            business_type_id: this.business_ids_filter, 
            limit:20 
        })
        .then((data: any) => {
            this.fairCustomers.splice(0, this.fairCustomers.length);
            this.fairCustomers.push(data);
            this.Refresh('fairCustomers');
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('failed get fairCustomers from server ', err);
        });
    }
```

---

Now, you of course need to make sure that the array actually is an array if you use `in:`.